# Really simple MySQL JOIN not working?

Tags: mysql, join, syntax-error

What am I doing wrong? Seriously confused.

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
WHERE user_id = 1
JOIN photos_albums ON photos_albums.photo_id = photos.id
```

The context is, I have a table to store photos, and another table to store photo albums (not shown). I also have a cross-referencing table `photos_albums` to store which photos are in which albums.

I get given a Syntax Error. eh?

Thanks!

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WHERE clause must come after the joins, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
INNER JOIN photos_albums 
  ON (photos_albums.photo_id = photos.id)
WHERE user_id = 1
```

See [manual page for SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) for all the gory details.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` should come at the end; try modifying it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM photos p JOIN photos_albums pa ON pa.photo_id = p.id
WHERE p.user_id = 1
```